# Timeout during commit in @Startup of @Singleton after update to Weblogic 12.2.1.2.0

Tags: jakarta-ee, singleton, startup, weblogic12c

We have upgraded our environment to `WLS12.2.1.2.0` coming from `WLS12.1.1.0` and have encountered a problem with transactions in the `@Startup` method of a `@Singleton` bean.

Said bean is deployed within an EAR that publishes a message to a JMS queue under a transaction. This works when the targeted server is running, but fails during container startup with:

```
Timeout during commit processing
at weblogic.rjvm.ResponseImpl.unmarshalReturn(ResponseImpl.java:281)
at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicRemoteRef.invoke(BasicRemoteRef.java:301)
at weblogic.transaction.internal.CoordinatorImpl_12212_WLStub.commit(Unknown Source)
at weblogic.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl$1.run(TransactionImpl.java:378)
at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:368)
at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:163)
at weblogic.transaction.internal.SecureAction.runAction(SecureAction.java:71)
at weblogic.transaction.internal.PlatformHelperImpl.runAction(PlatformHelperImpl.java:1493)
at weblogic.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:375)
at weblogic.transaction.internal.ServerTransactionImpl.internalCommit(ServerTransactionImpl.java:270)
at weblogic.transaction.internal.ServerTransactionImpl.commit(ServerTransactionImpl.java:257)
at weblogic.ejb.container.manager.BaseEJBManager.handleLifecycleCallbackTx(BaseEJBManager.java:412)
at weblogic.ejb.container.manager.SingletonSessionManager.constructAndInitBean(SingletonSessionManager.java:301)
...
Caused by: javax.transaction.SystemException: Timeout during commit processing
at weblogic.transaction.internal.ServerTransactionImpl.internalCommit(ServerTransactionImpl.java:340)
at weblogic.transaction.internal.ServerTransactionImpl.commit(ServerTransactionImpl.java:257)
at weblogic.transaction.internal.CoordinatorImpl.commit(CoordinatorImpl.java:99)
at weblogic.transaction.internal.CoordinatorImpl_WLSkel.invoke(Unknown Source)
at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef.invoke(BasicServerRef.java:645)
at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef$2.run(BasicServerRef.java:534)
at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:368)
at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:163)
at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef.handleRequest(BasicServerRef.java:531)
at weblogic.rmi.internal.wls.WLSExecuteRequest.run(WLSExecuteRequest.java:138)
... 7 more
```

We have been able to recreate this issue with a plain example setup: a simple `@Singleton` bean with a `@Startup` method that tries to use a transaction. However, the specification seems to outline that transaction behavior during startup should be possible, with the transaction fully comitting once the server finishes startup.

What causes this issue in `WLS12.2.1.2.0` and what is the preferred way of working around it?

Comment: What do you mean by "This works when the targeted server is running, but fails during container startup" ? I have the dame kind of problem  with sending a JMS message to a JMS queue in a Transactional Rest resource after upgrading from wls 12.1.3 to 12.2.1

Comment: @Rouliboy I mean that if we let the deployment fail, and try again after the server start is complete, the transaction in [at]Startup is both started and finished instead of never comitting.